# Java Servlet download error

Tags: java, servlets, restlet

This code only works with Firefox:

```
    @Override
    public void run(Representation entity) {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = null;
        try {
            httpServletResponse = ServletUtils.getResponse(getResponse());
            OutputStream buffOs = new BufferedOutputStream(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
            CountingOutputStream countingOutputStream = new CountingOutputStream(buffOs);
            OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(countingOutputStream,"UTF-8");
            httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/csv;charset=utf-8");
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "Chunked");
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=\"" + FILE_NAME + ".csv\"");
            CSVFunction method = new CSVFunction(outputWriter);
            System.out.println("TOTAL BYTES: " + countingOutputStream.getCount());
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Length", countingOutputStream.getCount() + "");
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().flush();
            httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

I have tried Chrome and Opera browsers but all of those are throwing a Download error. The `CSVFunction` takes a bit of time to finish, processing around 30K rows. I wonder why Firefox can handle this properly and while Chrome and Opera cannot. The only time this works with Chrome is if I force the row processing to say 200 rows only (fast) then it works and returns the CSV generated.

What could be wrong here? Is there a workaround that this could work with Chrome?

*The CSVFunction is basically based on https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-java/*

Comment: It's not a good idea to call `httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()` more than once. Also, I think your `Content-Length` header is **very** wrong.

Comment: Content-Length is wrong?

Comment: I looked again; That is getting the number of bytes for the attachment. But you've already sent the body; so I don't think that's actually correct. You need to get the length before you send the body. Although, it's possible you fit in the buffer which makes it harder to speak definitively. Check with the chrome developer tools.

Comment: The problem is that the `CSVFunction` function has a for-loop that writes to the stream, now only after the loop is done that the Content-Length is known. That is the reason for the `CountingOutputStream`

Comment: I know. If you have the ram, write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. If you don't have the ram; you might try a reverse proxy.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch apparently this code worked when I changed from Jetty to Tomcat